# Best way to model data in Firebase

Tags: json, database, firebase

I am new to Firebase and am unfamiliar with the best way to model data. I am a web designer who's taken a liking to web dev and chose Firebase as  service due to its ease of use.

Right now I'm modeling my data as:

```
[Firebase Root]
    |
    +--userId  (Firebase unique UID)
        |
        +--Projects
               |
               + ProjectId (Firebase unique key)
                      |
                      +--Images
                           |
                           +--ImageId  (Firebase unique key)
                                 |
                                 +--Comments
                                      |
                                      +--CommentId  (Firebase unique key)
```

I'm wondering if this is good practice? How scalable / performant is it?

It looks bloated, but I have little experience with how to go about this and I'd like to design my app with best practices in mind.

Comment: In addition to Jay's answer, the Firebase documentation has great information on such things. For this specific case, see the section called [Use Nested Data Sparingly](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-nested).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Way big question. It really comes down to what you want to do with your data.

While there isn't anything technically wrong with that structure, it's nested pretty deep and because of that, getting data back out of it may be limited.

You really want to flatten your data whenever possible - the flatter the better.

One thought is to make your data re-usable. Not sure if that's part of your set up but something like this:

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Jeff"
  uid_1
    name: "Cole"

projects
  project_id_0
    user: uid_0
    images
      image_id_0: true
      image_id_1: true
    comments:
      comment_id_0: true
  project_id_1
    user: uid_1
      image_id_1: true
      comment_id_1: true
images
  image_id_0
    image: "link to some image"
  image_id_1
    image: "link to another image"

comments
  comment_id_0
     verbiage: "nice project_id_0!!!"
     made_by: user_id_0
     project: project_id_0
  comment_id_1
     verbiage: "project_id_1 is the best project evah"
     made_by: user_id_1
     project: project_id_1
```

With this structure, your projects have the user, images and comments tied to it by reference and it's pretty shallow - easy to get to your data.

You could even expand this out a bit and assign multiple users to a single project.

If you notice, I cross linked the comments to the project and the project to the comments. That way you can easily query the comments node about a particular project (or made by a certain user) as well as when you have loaded in a project node (in code) you have direct access to which comments are about that project.

This also enables you to use the same image across multiple projects.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clear explanation and giving me some insight into how to model my project.